# Ask OP Question through edit

Tags: discussion, questions

Should a user be able to edit a question in such a way that additional questions are directed at the OP?

I have traditionally asked any questions in comments.

Comment: What?  John's not asking a question in the edit; he's just doing some minor format touch-ups.

Comment: Which portion is including more questions?  It just looks like a change in formatting to me.

Comment: There is nothing untoward about the last edit. The second revision is the OP editing their own post.

Comment: I apologize, I misunderstood what the revision was doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not ask for clarification etc. through edits.

That's what comments are for.

If you have less than 50 reputation points and can't comment simply move on and find another question to answer.